# How to split a integer string based on the character present in it

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, string, c#-4.0

So I will have list of integer strings, I mean, integers converted to strings in my DB like below:

```
66S12345, 623T4785, 784D3212
```

So there will be only one occurance of character in the above string.

Now I want to split the string based on the character position and obtain it as `S12345, T4785, D3212`. But no idea how to get it.

I obtain list of strings as below

```
using(var context=new ATMAccountEntities()){
     List<string> accountNumbers = new List<string>();
     accountNumbers = (from n in context.Students select n.stdUniqueID).ToList();
     foreach(var acc in accountNumbers) // acc can be 66S12345, 623T4785, 784D3212
     {
          string accNum=  //Any way to split the string and obtain later part after character
     }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below regex to resolve it

```
string obj = "784D3212";               
            Match match = Regex.Match(obj, @"[A-Z]\d+");
            if (match.Success)
                obj = match.Value;
```

Comment: `Regex reg = new Regex("");` --  What is that for?  Your regex seems okay, but that line makes no sense.

Comment: That worked! Just one last doubt! If I want integers after that character how to obtain that like in the answer you mentioned I want only `3212`

Comment: string obj = "784D3212";
                  MatchCollection matchs = Regex.Matches(obj, @"\d+");
            obj = matchs[1].Value;
        }